# Aspects generated by Roo no longer on Classpath

Tags: spring, aspectj

I have been using Spring Roo with SpringSource Tool Suite for the past 10 months with no problem. Now, while my code continues to compile in Maven, none of the generated aspects are on the classpath in Eclipse, so I am getting red flag errors for all of invocations of code generated by Roo, for example: getters and setters, finders on the entities and the toString().
The roo .aj files are generated side by side with the entities, so

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooEntity
public class Applicant extends Responsibility {

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "applicant")
    private ApplicantProfile applicantProfile;

}
```

produces Applicant_Roo_Configurable.aj, Applicant_Roo_ToString.aj, Applicant_Roo_Entity.aj
e.g.

```
privileged aspect Applicant_Roo_JavaBean {

public ApplicantProfile Applicant.getApplicantProfile() {
    return this.applicantProfile;
}

public void Applicant.setApplicantProfile(ApplicantProfile applicantProfile) {
    this.applicantProfile = applicantProfile;
}
```

}

Comment: Does the Roo generated `aj` files exist physical? (what ever physical mean to a file)

Comment: Thanks, Ralph, yes I've modified the post to show this.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities that I can see:

1. Your project is not an AspectJ project.  In the .project file (hidden by default, but "Open resource can find it), you should see `org.eclipse.ajdt.ui.ajnature` as one of the natures.
2. The .aj files have been excluded from the build.

if #1, then select project, right-click, Configure -> Convert to AspectJ project.  If #2, then Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source and remove all exclusion filters from all source folders.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the pointers Andrew. As you mentioned in point #2 above, for some reason, my .aj files were automatically excluded from the build.

I included '**/*.aj' in  Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source. Worked like a charm.